# How to pass a default Input to my invoked PowerShell command

Tags: c#, powershell

I have a Powershell script which I have invoked from a C# method. While doing it locally, I get a prompt where I have to select Yes or No and I select YES and things work as expected. But when pushed to server, it fails, I would like to know how can I select default as YES in my code so that the same goes in server and I don't have to worry about. here is my C# method and powershell script which is invoked after which i get a prompt.

```
public void CreateDatabaseFromPowerShell()
        {
            string path = Path.Combine( Root, @"TestData\CosmosScript.ps1" );
            Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
            runspace.Open();
            Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
            pipeline.Commands.AddScript( path );
            Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
            runspace.Close();           
        }

----Import-Module "$env:ProgramFiles\Azure Cosmos DB Emulator\PSModules\Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Emulator"
----Start-CosmosDbEmulator
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the PowerShell SDK, *interactive* prompts cannot be responded to (programmatically), so any PowerShell command executed via the SDK that tries to ask the user for interactive input *fails*.

Here's a simple demonstration from PowerShell:

```sh
PS> ($ps = [PowerShell]::Create()).AddCommand('Read-Host').Invoke()

Exception calling "Invoke" with "0" argument(s):
"A command that prompts the user failed because the host program or the command type 
does not support user interaction [...]"
```

Your only option is to *avoid* such prompts, with command parameters such as `-Force` and `-Confirm:$false` - check the syntax of the command of interest to see which parameter applies (or possibly both).

Note that while [`Import-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module) does have a `-Force` parameter (but no `-Confirm` parameter), it never requests interactive input *itself*.
(The module being imported may trigger a prompt, however, such as the *system*'s UAC prompt to confirm the intent to run with *elevation* (as admin)  - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68180541/45375).

Comment: Please see my detailed explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68180541/45375). If something is still unclear, please ask there.